# Django REST Framework change rederer class based on response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-drf-renderer

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **Django REST Framework**.

I have an `APIView` which will download Zip file on success response.

```
class MultiDownloadCode(APIView):

    serializer_class = MultiDownloadSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticated,
        CodeCanExport,
    )
    renderer_classes = (ZipRenderer,)

    def post(self, request):
        ...
        mime_type = 'application/zip'

        file_name = '{}.zip'.format(random_string(20))

        response = Response(data=in_memory_zip.read(), content_type=mime_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % "-".join(file_name.split())

        return response
```

I have created a custom Renderer class `ZipRenderer`

```
class ZipRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/zip'
    format = 'zip'
    charset = 'utf-8'
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data
```

This is working fine in case of a successful response. But in case of permission denied exception, the error messages are also binary encoded and not proper JSON rendered.

When I add `JSONRenderer` to the `renderer_classes`

```
renderer_classes = (ZipRenderer, JSONRenderer)
```

This works fine in case of exception but then gives error in case of a success response.

**How can I change the renderer based on the response?**

Comment: Which error do you have? And which value of "accepted content types" header is on the input?